# Why does some peoples' hair look blue when I look out the train window while wearing sunglasses?

Tags: visible-light, polarization

Specifically, when I look through the window, black hair looks blue when people pass the window outside, and black shiny benches look like somebody painted them blue.

Pretty sure my sunglasses are polarized (they've got the red tint stuff on them). The window just looks like a thick piece of single-layer glass (it's an emergency exit window so it's pretty big).

To add a bit more info:

1. When I am outside and I look at black things while wearing my sunglasses, they don't look blue (only when I also look through the window)
2. When I look through the window without my sunglasses, black things look normal.

This combination of sunglasses and the window seems to make black things blue... Why is this?

Comment: You can tell whether your glasses are polarized by looking a polarized source (such as an LCD TV or monitor or obliquely reflected light) and rotating them. I don't think the "red tint stuff" implies polarization.